# Saving PDF with cyrillic text in Unity3D using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, unity-game-engine, itext

I create a BaseFont using that code

```
string combineStr                       = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath+"/Resources/Fonts", "Calibri Regular.ttf");
BaseFont bf                             = BaseFont.CreateFont(combineStr, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
iTextSharp.text.Font titleFont          = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10f, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

Testing it in Unity everything works fine, and my cyrillic glyphs working well, but in WindowsPalyer build i get an error

```
ArgumentException: Encoding name 'windows-1252' not supported
Paremeter name: name.
```

Cant find any problem here.. Checked everything, and how I see my BaseFont code is correct. What is wrong in my case? 
P.S. I have tried also others fonts with cyrillic support, but nothing helps.

Comment: 1. Why aren't you embedding the font? This means that the PDF won't be legible on every platform. 2. You are using Unicode, why would the encoding `windows-1252` be needed? 3. You talk about Cyrillic glyphs, but the encoding for Cyrillic is 1251 not 1252. All of this leads to believe that you're not telling us everything you should. I don't know what Unity3d is, so I have no idea what is throwing the exception. It doesn't look like an iTextSharp exception, though. Are you by any chance passing a `string` encoded using the windows-1252 encoding? Maybe that's not supported on the client?

Comment: Thanks for reply
1) I found that solution in internet, where people ask for "How to work with cyrillic in iTextSharp" And ofcourse I already tried to make it EMBEDDED
2) The same - from solutions. But I was thinking about UTF-8, but didnt find the solution in iTextSharp.. Sorry,  I just explored that library 1 day, dont know a lot, and not sure that will use it often
3) I didnt choose BaseFont.CP1252 .. .I dont know why error show me that encoding. In solutions in internet everybody reccomend BaseFont.IDENTITY_H

Comment: here is a full error message
[link](http://puu.sh/gnVvg/ecad88ebbb.png)

Comment: Bruno thank you, Because of your mind that it is not a iTextSharp error, I found a solution in missing .dll

Comment: Great! It would be nice if you added that comment as an answer, so that people see that the problem is resolved.

Comment: I think I did it already. There is no answers to mark it correct, only comments. So I wrote that text in question field

Comment: I have removed your answer from your question and I've added it as a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

The OP added the solution to the question. I'm removing it from the question, adding it as a real answer:

The issue here is that I18N.dll and I18N.West.dll are missing in the standalone player.They are available in the editor, though. That's why it's working in the editor but not in the standalone player.

Solution: Put those DLLs into your project (probably best next to System.Data.dll), that way, they will be also available in the standalone player.

See also [CodePage 1252 not supported - works in editor but not in standalone player](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/42955/codepage-1252-not-supported-works-in-editor-but-no.html) on Unity Answers.